# i use pagecontroller to animation page but when i push to next page than i am back pagecontroller error

Tags: flutter, dart

```
Error: Assertion failed: file:///Users/vannak/Documents/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/scroll_controller.dart:108:12
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 266:49                           throw_
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 29:3                             assertFailed
packages/flutter/src/widgets/scroll_controller.dart 108:33                                             get position
packages/flutter/src/widgets/page_view.dart 196:41                                                     animateToPage
packages/rentkhapp/src/modules/map_module/map_property/controller/property_map_controller.dart 416:35  <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/async/future.dart 424:39                                                                  <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/isolate_helper.dart 48:19                                internalCallback
Another exception was thrown: [object Event]
```

Comment: could you please add your code too?

Comment: did you override the dispose ?